# Successful API call returning null value when using Single.zip()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using `Single.zip()` and Function 5 to consolidate 5 API calls into one Single:

```
private fun loadProfileAndBalances() {


        registerSubscription(
                Single.zip<AvailableFundsResult, IncomingFundsResult, TotalEarnedResult, TotalDonatedResult, ProfileResult, Unit>(
                        Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getAvailableFunds()
                                .map<AvailableFundsResult> {

                                    Timber.d("Available Result [${it.amount}]") <------ DollarAmount object with null amount
                                    AvailableFundsResult.Amount(it) }
                                .onErrorReturn { AvailableFundsResult.Error(it) }
                                .scheduleIOUI(),

                        Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getIncomingFunds()
                                .map<IncomingFundsResult> { IncomingFundsResult.Amount(it) }
                                .onErrorReturn { IncomingFundsResult.Error(it) }
                                .scheduleIOUI(),

                        Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getTotalEarned()
                                .map<TotalEarnedResult> { TotalEarnedResult.Amount(it) }
                                .onErrorReturn { TotalEarnedResult.Error(it) }
                                .scheduleIOUI(),

                        Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getTotalDonated()
                                .map<TotalDonatedResult> { TotalDonatedResult.Amount(it) }
                                .onErrorReturn { TotalDonatedResult.Error(it) }
                                .scheduleIOUI(),

                        Interactors.profileManager.getNotCachedProfile()
                                .map<ProfileResult> { ProfileResult.Profile(it) }
                                .onErrorReturn { ProfileResult.Error(it) }
                                .scheduleIOUI(),

                        Function5 { availableFunds: AvailableFundsResult, incomingFunds: IncomingFundsResult, totalEarned: TotalEarnedResult, totalDonated: TotalDonatedResult, profileResult: ProfileResult ->

                            availableTotal = when (availableFunds) {
                                is AvailableFundsResult.Amount ->
                                    availableFunds.result.amount

                                is AvailableFundsResult.Error -> {
                                    Timber.w(availableFunds.throwable, "Error while fetching sponsorships")
                                    "0.00"
                                }
                            }

                            incomingTotal = when (incomingFunds) {
                                is IncomingFundsResult.Amount -> incomingFunds.result.amount

                                is IncomingFundsResult.Error -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.payout_main_error_loading_totals), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    "0.00"
                                }
                            }

                            earnedTotal = when (totalEarned) {
                                is TotalEarnedResult.Amount -> totalEarned.result.amount

                                is TotalEarnedResult.Error -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.payout_main_error_loading_totals), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    "0.00"
                                }

                            }

                            donatedTotal = when (totalDonated) {
                                is TotalDonatedResult.Amount -> totalDonated.result.amount

                                is TotalDonatedResult.Error -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.payout_main_error_loading_totals), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    "0.00"
                                }

                            }

                            onboardingComplete = when (profileResult) {
                                is ProfileResult.Profile ->
                                    profileResult.result.isOnboardingCompleted


                                is ProfileResult.Error -> {
                                    Timber.e(profileResult.throwable, "Error fetching profile")
                                    true
                                }

                            }


                        }
                ).ignoreElement()
                        .subscribe(::updateViews) {
                            it.printStackTrace()
                            availableTotal = ""
                            incomingTotal = ""
                            earnedTotal = ""
                            donatedTotal = ""
                            onboardingComplete= false
                            vWalletRefresher.isRefreshing = false
                            internetConnectionError(it)
                        })


}
```

Each of these API calls is succeeding with code 200. The call made with Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getAvailableFunds() is returning `{"amount":264.69}`, which is parsed into an object of this class:

```
internal data class DollarAmount(@SerializedName("amount") val amount: String)
```

The paymentsApiClient repeatedly referenced is built like this:

```
 private fun createNewPaymentsClient(authRefreshClient: AuthRefreshClient,
                                   preferencesInteractor: PreferencesInteractor): PaymentsApiClient {

    val loggingInterceptor = run {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }
    }


    val okHttpClient = createHttpClientBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(createSessionRequestInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(createUserAgentInterceptor(context))
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .authenticator(RefreshUserAuthenticator(authRefreshClient, preferencesInteractor,
                    UnauthorizedNavigator(SDKInternal.appContext, Interactors.preferences)))
            .build()


    val gson = GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setLenient().create()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(Interactors.apiEndpoint)
            .build()
            .create(PaymentsApiClient::class.java)

}
```

Despite the API call being successful, the log statement that is printed in Single.zip for a successful retrieval of a DollarAmount via `Interactors.api.paymentsApiClient.getAvailableFunds()` the is showing its amount as being null, rather than 264.69. What is wrong with my parsing that is making this null?

Edit: As someone noticed, I am wrapping the results in another set of classes:

```
   private sealed class AvailableFundsResult {
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : AvailableFundsResult()
    data class Amount(val result: DollarAmount) : AvailableFundsResult()
}

private sealed class IncomingFundsResult {
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : IncomingFundsResult()
    data class Amount(val result: DollarAmount) : IncomingFundsResult()
}

private sealed class TotalEarnedResult {
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : TotalEarnedResult()
    data class Amount(val result: DollarAmount) : TotalEarnedResult()
}

private sealed class TotalDonatedResult {
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : TotalDonatedResult()
    data class Amount(val result: DollarAmount) : TotalDonatedResult()
}

private sealed class ProfileResult {
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : ProfileResult()
    data class Profile(val result: InfluencerProfileDto) : ProfileResult()
}
```

I don't think this is relevant though because it the amount is coming back null before I even spit out an instance of these wrapper classes.

Edit 2: Class that gets returned from 5th API call:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
internal data class InfluencerProfileDto(
        @Json(name = "id") val id: String,
        @Json(name = "emailAddress") val email: String?,
        @Json(name = "phoneNumber") val phoneNumber: PhoneNumberDto?,
        @Json(name = "isPhoneNumberVerified") val isPhoneNumberVerified: Boolean,
        @Json(name = "isEmailVerified") val isEmailVerified: Boolean,
        @Json(name = "notificationTimePreference") val notificationTimePreference: String,
        @Json(name = "isInstagramConnected") val isInstagramConnected: Boolean,
        @Json(name = "isFacebookConnected") val isFacebookConnected: Boolean,
        @Json(name = "isTwitterConnected") val isTwitterConnected: Boolean,
        @Json(name = "currencyIsoSymbol") val currencyIsoSymbol: String,
        @Json(name = "currencySymbol") val currency: String,
        @Json(name = "birthDate") val birthDate: Date?,
        @Json(name = "name") val name: String?,
        @Json(name = "profilePictureUri") val avatarUrl: String?,
        @Json(name = "gender") val gender: Gender?)

{


    val isOnboardingCompleted: Boolean
        get() = gender!= Gender.UNKNOWN && birthDate!= null && !!notificationTimePreference.isNullOrEmpty() && isPhoneNumberVerified && !email.isNullOrEmpty()
}
```

Comment: i love rx. the way you have done is a bit differnet than i do. for small HTTP requets use volley. its just so easy to use. for using single.zip dont put the code in the iterator itself and moreover the object building in the single.zip is a bit confusing. `Function5 { availableFunds: AvailableFundsResult, ...` seems wrong to me you ll be getting a list of object that you have to handle in that function and the code ll be reduced to 10 lines

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my post to show that wrapper class. It does seem frivilous but I'm basing these calls off of another set in the app that does it like this. Are you saying I should just put the API calls in Single.zip() and then put the result type (DollarAmount) in Function5? How do I error handle that way?

Comment: can you put comment in your question where you are getting unexpected values and till what point the code works as expected

Comment: I just drew an arrow next to the log statement that shows a DollarAmount object with a null amount,  despite the log from okhttp showing a response of {"amount":264.69}

Comment: and at what point you get the right values ? are you getting all other values right ?

Comment: The final call (Interactors.profileManager.getNotCachedProfile()) is getting it's result parsed properly when I check via a similar log statement in the result. The other's return strings in the API call but all become null in .map{}

Comment: did you try logging all other values ? in all other map functions in respective calls?

Comment: Just did, they all come back null except for the attribute retrieved from Interactors.profileManager.getNotCachedProfile(), I've included the class retrieved from that call in my second edit for your reference.

Comment: try using volley so much work ll be reduced and for using single.zip you shoud be using list it ll also reduce the code. if you can understand i can write an implementation in java

Comment: I would appreciated that thank you

Comment: ok wait i m writing ;)

Answer (score 0):

my approach is in java

first of all we need two libraries that you might not be using in your project ie.

`gson` => for pasing objects from string and vice versa

`volley` => for string http requests

please google their official github pages and install the latest versions

then we ll be creating a common result object to bear results

```
class Result {
   boolean error; // this field can be used by the api to tell if there was some error while processing the request
   String message; // here api can give you some extra message if there was some error
   String result; // here you get the result. you can make it a map as well if you want to receive an object and later parse to a unique object class
}
```

this is a function you can use for HTTP requets

```
public static Single<Result> getHttpResult(String api, Map<Stirng, String> params){
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, api, response -> {
                Log.i("RESPONSE :", response);
                try {
                    Result result = new Gson().fromJson(response, Result.java);
                    emitter.onSuccess(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    emitter.onError(e);
                }
            }, emitter::onError) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                return params;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0, 0, 0));
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    });

}
```

this is how you can get multiple results at once and i recommend you also check the internet connectivity if user has enough internet then only make parallel requests else it wont produce good UX

```
...

List<Single<Result>> tasks = new ArrayList();
tasks.add(getHttpResult("https://..."), /**here you can add a map with params that your api might require for auth and other purposes**/);
tasks.add(...);
tasks.add(...);
tasks.add(...);

Single.zip(tasks, objects -> {
   List<Result> results = new ArrayList();
   for(Object object : objects){
      results.add((Result)object)
   }
   return results;
}).subscribe(results -> {
   // this result object have all the results of http requests
   // for distinguising results from each other you can create a field on the result object 
});

...
```

hope my approach is helpful to you ;)